# Debugging , how do i stop it from asking to enter the number. I want it to ask once, and then stop

Tags: python, while-loop

```
#############
# Problem 3 #
#############
# Find the error in the following code.
# Fix the problem
# Uncomment the coded lines for this problem.

cube = 0
finished = False

while not finished:
    value = 0.0
    value = int(input('Enter a value to be cubed or zero (0) to stop: '))
    cube = value**3
    print(value,' cubed is ', cube)
    if (value == 0):
        print('Thank you!')
```

I tried to run it, it is running, but it is not stopping, after asking me to enter number.

Comment: If you want it to ask just once, get rid of the `while` loop.

Comment: Add `break` or `finished = True` if `value == 0`

Comment: There's no point in `value = 0.0`, since you overwrite it on the next line.

Comment: Put a `break` statement inside the `if value == 0` block.

Comment: You have a while loop.   The termination value is `finished`.  Somewhere in the loop you need to  change the value (which starts as False) in order to terminate the loop.